# What is this component name

Tags: java, swing, jlist

What is the name of the component in java Swing shown in the following link
http://www.scriptocean.com/template3.html

It is known as extended [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in Android. But I want to know the same in Java Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this component ?

[image: A list]

If so, to display it in Java, you have some choices.

- If you want your items to be easily clickable (that's to say action senders), you would tend to use [`JButtons`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) in a vertical [`BoxLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) 'ed [`JPanel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)
- If you simply want to display items, then customize their display, you would **undoubtly** go the [`JList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) way. Also take a look at [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), which is always of great help.

**EDIT**

Accordint o comment, to have an area below the button displaying content, you'll use the second solution with a twist. As all elements in Swing are in fact JComponents and can be put in thers, you'll use `JPanel` as `JList` elements. in each JPanel, you'll have ione button always visible and one sub-panel that is hidden at startup. When clicking the JButton, you'll simply show or hide the associated sub-panel. If you want to have some kind of effect, you can either

- wait for the upcoming JavaFX transitions effects
- Use [Filthy Rcih Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) animations library (take a look at their links page).

Comment: If we click in any of the button, it opens an editable area and lower buttons gets slided to lower. So how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard Swing component that behaves like in your example. But you can find something similar in the [SwingX project](http://www.swinglabs.org) : the **JXTaskPane** and **JXTaskPaneContainer** components.

Unlike your example, the sections are not exclusive. But you can achieve this exclusivity with a few lines of code.